# List of reusable CSS classes for Modern UI

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, modern-experience

Is there a table of all re-usable mdoern CSS classes? That would be useful to have in one place so that we can use them for JSON column formatting or in our custom SPFx webparts?

For example, I am talking about these classes:

- `sp-css-backgroundColor-neutralBackground`
- `sp-css-backgroundColor-success`
- `sp-css-backgroundColor-blueBackground07`
- `sp-css-backgroundColor-warningBackground`
- `sp-css-backgroundColor-successBackground`
- `sp-css-backgroundColor-blockingBackground`
- `sp-css-backgroundColor-errorBackground`
- etc.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I have extracted all Modern SharePoint CSS classess and made it available [as a page](https://zerg00s.github.io/sp-modern-classes/). You can see all available classes and see what it looks like when applied to an HTML element. Enjoy!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, this helped me alot!